# Erro ao dar espaços entre divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estou com um problema para da espaço em algumas divs, segue código abaixo:

HTML:

```
<div id="feira"> 
     <div class="barraca"></div> 
     <div class="barraca"></div> 
     <div class="barraca"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#feira{
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 55;
   width: 80%;
}

.barraca{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #AAA;
   width: 250px;
   height: 200px;
}
```

Agora para deixar as barracas separadas estou usando esse algoritmo em Jquery, mas não está dando certo, pois a 2º barraca ele fala que tem o left: 0; e uma das barraca fica  atras da outra.

Jquery:

```
function organizar(){
   qtdJanela = $(".barraca").size();
   if(qtdJanela > 1){
      for(c = 0; c < qtdJanela; c++){
          janela = $(".barraca").eq(c);
          posJanela = janela.position();
          distancia = posJanela.left;
          alert(distancia);
          $(".barraca").eq(c+1).css({'right':distancia+'px'});
      }
   }
}
```

Tem uma hora que ele apresenta 0 no distancia.

http://jsfiddle.net/zohx8s6y/

Comment: Mas porque você está usando um algoritmo em jQuery ? dá pra fazer isto com css puro.

Comment: porque preciso que ele fique fixo no bottom, estilo chat do face, pois vou minimizar a janela e só vai ficar o titulo sendo exibido. Com o position relative não fica fixo no bottom.

Comment: Mas se quer fazer igual ao chat do facebook terá que usar `position: fixed;` não `relative;`.

Comment: Sim eu sei, a div principal é fixed, mas as janelas precisa ficar como absolute para ficar com o bottom 0.

Comment: Claro que não, se você define o `bottom: 0px` na `div` pai que é `fixed` vai ficar no footer. De uma olhada neste exemplo que fiz no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/4v0n8qpe/). Você também pode optar pela especificação [flexible box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Olha como no que quero usar http://jsfiddle.net/f5x2tqad/. Seu eu deixar sem ser absotute, veja o que acontece ao minimizar a janela!

Comment: Entendi, caso alguém não acha uma resposta para seu problema, quando tiver tempo, vou desenvolver uma solução enxuta e performática.

Comment: Ok, obrigado! ^^

Comment: @RomarioPires, é isto que você deseja? https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/17sj3oxp/

Comment: realizei uma atualização no script: https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/17sj3oxp/1/

Comment: Vlw cara consegui resolver já. O que eu precisava é que ficasse fixo no bottom da tela, não pode sair mesmo dando scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar essa atividade, segue o código abaixo:

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="feira"></div>
<button>Organizar</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Código CSS:**

```
#feira{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    border:3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}

.barraca {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #AAA;
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 150px;
   right: 0px;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```

**Código jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var aumentarLargura = $("#feira").width();
        aumentarLargura += $(".barraca").width() + 10;
        $("#feira").width(aumentarLargura + "px");
        $("#feira").append("<div class=\"barraca\"></div>");
    });
});
```

Para visualizar, segue o link abaixo:

[Espaçamento entre divs via jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/do5tktjx/)

Comment: Vlw cara consegui resolver já. O que eu precisava é que ficasse fixo no bottom da tela, não pode sair mesmo dando scroll.

Comment: Entendi, tranquilo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de você poder usar o jQuery, é melhor nesse caso você usar o css. Para dar o espaçamento basta usar a propriedade margin. Ficaria assim:

```
.barraca{
margin: 15px; // junto com as propriedades que você usou
}
```

Com esse css acima, você teria um espaçamento de 15 pixels em todas as direções.

Comment: Mas não funciona com o position:absolute, e right: 0;